How do I run a server concurrently in GitHub Actions
I have configured the following workflow:
name: Python application

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "app" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "app" ]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: "3.10"
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        make install 
    - name: Lint with pylint
      run: |
        make lint
    - name: Start Fastapi service 
      run: |
        nohup make serve 
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        make test 

Here the Makefile for this is as follows:
install: 
    pip install -r requirements.txt 

lint: 
    pylint --disable=R,C *.py 

serve: 
    python app.py 

test: 
    python -m pytest -vv test_app.py 

The problem is, when I run the make serve command, the server starts and then goes on infinitely and never reaches the testing part. How do I configure my workflow such that the server runs in the backend and the testing starts? I have tried using nohup and it didn't work. What other things can I do?

Alternatively, you could consider this not really a GHA problem - it would be helpful to be able to start the server and run tests against it anywhere. For example: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2024/Aug/17/python-tdd-ohm.html#bonus

The issue you're encountering is that when you run the command nohup make serve, it starts the FastAPI server in the background but doesn’t release control back to the GitHub Actions workflow immediately. Since the server runs indefinitely, the subsequent make test command does not execute as expected.
To solve this, you can run your FastAPI service in a way that allows the GitHub Actions workflow to continue with the next steps, like running tests.
name: Python application

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "app" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "app" ]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: "3.10"
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        make install 
    - name: Start FastAPI service
      run: |
        make serve &
        sleep 5  # Give the server some time to start
    - name: Wait for FastAPI service to start
      run: |
        for i in {1..10}; do
          if curl -s http://localhost:8000/; then
            echo "Service is up!"
            break
          fi
          echo "Waiting for service to start..."
          sleep 5
        done
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        make test 

With these changes, your server should run in the background, allowing the tests to execute afterward.

Thank you. It worked, but I do not understand why exactly it worked. For starters:
When I run make serve & sleep 5, it runs the endpoint and THEN it should sleep right? But if the make serve command never exists how does it ever move to the next step of sleeping?

When placing an & at the end of a command it is run in the background and execution is continued directly.
